# Remove blank option after filter

Tags: angularjs

My problem is when I use a custom filter on ngOptions it creates a blank option. What I want is to have the first index of the filtered array to be selected and therefore the blank option removed.

I've search this forum for similar problems, but couldn't find any posts that addressed my problem - or I'm unable to understand the answers :)

Some of the things I've tried:

```
ng-init="option.selectedEnd=$first"
ng-init="option.selectedEnd=oppositeEnds[0]"
ng-selected="$first"
```

I've created a short fiddle for you guys: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cphdj74/og2f2qqr/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty option is generated when a value referenced by ng-model doesn't exist in a set of options passed to ng-options.

If you want to get rid of the empty option just select an initial value in your controller, something like:

```
$scope.form.type = $scope.typeOptions[0].value;
```

Here is the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/3/

You need to select a valid model value to get rid of this empty option.

Comment: @DannyBoy, you can add into your code this foreach

`angular.forEach($scope.options, function (opt) {
        opt.selectedEnd = $filter('inArray')($scope.oppositeEnds, opt.oppositeEnds, 'code')[0];`

**EDIT**
Also don't forget add `$filter` into arguments of your controller like this: `function myController($scope, $filter) {`

Comment: @axon, hmm i'm not sure where to put it. I've tried your solution and angular crashes

Comment: @axon, Arh! I was missing a closing paranthese - Thank you sir! It works. How can I giv you the points for answer?

Comment: you're welcome!

I think you should accept @kaushal-khamar's answer, because he explained what was your problem :)